# Rebase branch preserving commits on another branch based on it

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-rebase

Sorry if the title is misleading, but I'm not really sure how to describe the situation I've got.

I've commits and branches like this

```
A --- B --- C --- D (master)
                   \
                    E (another)
```

and I want to remove commits `B` and `C` (preserving `D`) from `master` branch but keep them in `another` branch which is based on master.
So after the transformation my tree should look like this:

```
A --- D (master)
 \
  B --- C --- E (another)
```

I figured, that I probably should just rebase `master`, but then I'm not sure if `B` and `C` will still be included in `another` not to mention removing / omitting `D` from it.

How should I proceed to achieve effect discribed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to move the changesets, It should not be that hard:

```
git rebase --onto A C master
```

This will move branch `master` to be on top of A, discard revisions up to C (so only D will me moved, along with the branch pointer). Then:

```
git rebase --onto C D another
```

This will rebase E on top of C, discard revisions up to D (in other words, move only E on top of C...move branch pointer as well).

That should do.

Comment: I've updated my current tree graph to make more clear that `another` is currently based on top of `master`. I assume this will work anyway for such case, right?

Comment: this seems like a good answer but I'd like to see the explanation move from a bash comment I have to scroll to see, to a bit of explanation outside the snippet.

Comment: Never mind, tested it and worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To get the result you'd like—well, what *might be* the result you would like, at least—you have to stop using existing commits `D` and `E` entirely, and the reason for that is that no one—not you or Git itself—can change *anything* about *any* existing commit entirely, and the connections *between* commits are actually hash IDs stored *inside* the child of the parent/child pair.

That is, given the first drawing, commit `A` is a root commit: it has no parent.  There is no arrow saying *the commit before `A` is _____* as there is no commit before `A`.  But commit `B` *does* have an arrow, pointing from it to commit `A`: *the commit before me is commit `A`*.  Commit `C` contains an arrow pointing to `B`; `D` contains an arrow pointing to `C`; and `E` contains an arrow pointing to `D`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E
```

Unlike *commits*, branch names *can* be changed: they act as arrows pointing to any one commit of your choice.  So `master` currently points to existing commit `D`, and `another` points to existing commit `E`.  Git can start from `another` to find `E`, use `E` to find `D`, use `D` to find `C`, and so on; or Git can start from `master` to find `D`, which finds `C` and `B` and `A`.

The result you'd like has a commit `B` pointing back to `A`, and `C` pointing back to `B`, so existing commits through `C` are all fine.  But you'd like to have a new-and-improved variant of `D`, which instead of pointing to `C`, points directly to `A`.

This new-and-improved `D'` presumably has a snapshot that no existing commit has.  To make the snapshot for `D'`, you'd like Git to take the difference between the snapshots in `C` and `D`, and apply that difference to the snapshot in `A`.

Git can do this automatically.  The base Git command that does this is `git cherry-pick`.  We'll see in a moment how to use `git rebase` to *run* (the right set of) `git cherry-pick` commands, but let's start with cherry-pick itself.

Similarly, you want a new-and-improved *copy* of `E`, which we can call `E'`, in which the improvement is:

- point back to `C`, not `D`; and
- have a snapshot that is made by applying the difference between snapshots `D` and `E` to the snapshot that's in `C`.

Again, this is a job for `git cherry-pick`.  So let's look at how to do that.

#### Using `git cherry-pick`

To make new-and-improved `D'` whose parent is `A`, we must first `git checkout` commit `A` itself, preferably also attaching a temporary branch name there to avoid confusion.  (Internally, with `git rebase`, Git does all of this with *no* temporary branch name.)  So we'll run:

```
git checkout -b temp <hash-of-A>
```

which gives us:

```
A   <-- temp (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E   <-- another
```

Now we use `git cherry-pick` like so:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-D>
# or: git cherry-pick master
```

This copies commit `D`, the one to which `master` points—we can give it by its hash ID, or by the name `master`—to new commit `D`', to which `temp` now points.  (Any time we make a new commit, Git stores the new commit's hash ID in the *current* branch: the one `HEAD` is attached to.  So `temp` now points to copy `D'`.)

```
A--D'  <-- temp (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E   <-- another
```

Now we need another new temporary branch, pointing to commit `C`, so we run `git checkout -b temp2 hash-of-C`.  (Instead of the raw hash, we can use any other way that Git has to find commit `C`, such as `master~1`, but raw hashes are fine with cut-and-paste, as long as you cut the right one.)  This give us:

```
A--D'  <-- temp
 \
  B--C   <-- temp2 (HEAD)
      \
       D   <-- master
        \
         E   <-- another
```

(Note how `HEAD` is now attached to `temp2`, because of the `git checkout -b`.)  Now we cherry-pick commit `E` to make `E'`:

```
git cherry-pick another
```

will do the trick since `another` points to commit `E`.  If all goes well, Git makes the new commit on its own and we have:

```
A--D'  <-- temp
 \
  B--C--E'  <-- temp2 (HEAD)
      \
       D   <-- master
        \
         E   <-- another
```

What we need to do now is force the name `master` to refer to commit `D'`, and the name `another` to refer to commit `E'`.  To do this now, we can just use `git branch -f`:

```
git branch -f master temp
git branch -f another temp2
```

which gives us:

```
A--D'  <-- master, temp
 \
  B--C--E'  <-- another, temp2 (HEAD)
      \
       D   [abandoned]
        \
         E   [abandoned]
```

Although commits `D` and `E` have no *names*—which makes them really hard to find—they'll linger on in your Git repository for quite a while, typically for at least 30 days.  (This is controllable via various *reflog* expiration settings.)  If you've saved their hash IDs somewhere (and you have—or rather, Git has saved the hash IDs in some reflogs), you can still get them back for this time period.

You can now `git checkout` either of the original branch names and delete both `temp` names.

#### Doing this with `git rebase`

What `git rebase` does is, in essence,<sup>1</sup> run a *series* of `git cherry-pick` commands, and finish everything off by running the equivalent of `git branch -f` to force the branch name to point to the *last* copied commit, and `git checkout` that branch.  The set of commits that `git rebase` will copy comes from what rebase calls its *upstream* argument.  The place to which rebase will copy them, as if by `git cherry-pick`, comes from what rebase calls its *onto* argument.

That is, you run:

```
git rebase --onto <target> <upstream>
```

where *`target`* is the commit you want to come *before* the first copied commit, and *`upstream`* tells Git what commits *not* to copy.  This "what not to copy" seems weird at first, but you get used to it.<sup>2</sup>  It also allows you to omit the `--onto` most of the time (though not in your particular case).

What Git does is enumerate the commits in `upstream..HEAD`, excluding certain usually-undesirable commits.<sup>3</sup>  This comes up with a list of commit hash IDs that should be copied / cherry-picked.  This list gets saved into a temporary file.<sup>4</sup>  Then, Git runs a HEAD-detaching variant of `git checkout` to check out the *`target`* commit for `--onto`, or *`upstream`* if you did not specify an `--onto`.  Then, Git does the cherry-picking of the saved hash IDs.  Last, if all has gone well, Git forcibly re-attaches the branch and its `HEAD` to the last copied commit from the rebase operation.

For your particular case, [eftshift0 has already shown the appropriate `git rebase` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885307/1256452), beating me to this answer by ~20 minutes. :-)  This is all just a long explanation of what's actually going on.

---

<sup>1</sup>I say *as if* by cherry-pick here because some rebase methods use other methods, and some rebases literally run `git cherry-pick`, or—in the most modern Git—are built directly into what Git calls, internally, the *sequencer*, which implements cherry-picking.

<sup>2</sup>It's actually natural because of Git's `A..B` limiting syntax.  This tells Git: *find commits that are **reachable from** `B`, excluding those **reachable from** `A`.*  For (much) more about reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

<sup>3</sup>The undesirables are existing merge commits, and any commit already cherry-picked.  Git finds the latter using the `git patch-id` program.  It's a little tricky to describe properly, and I won't go into details here.

<sup>4</sup>It's under `.git` but the location has moved throughout Git's development.  Depending on other things, you can sometimes find them in `.git/rebase-todo` or a similar name, if you're curious.

Comment: That's some amazing and precious knowledge. I really appreciate that you took time to explain it in such details. The only way I can visually show you my gratitude now is vote up, but your answer is the definition of how "passing knowledge" should look like. Once again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving it is to simply use interactive rebase:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Create another branch from master and rewrite them both manually:

```
$ git checkout -b another
$ git rebase -i
```

`git rebase` with no arguments will give you a list with all commits on that branch. Then simply mark the ones to delete with 'd' in the list of commits. e.g. for master you'd want to "remove" B, C and E.

```
d b72a395    E
pick 5bca8d9 D
d 15aab26    C
d 25aab26    B
pick 35aab26 A
```

For "another" branch,  mark "D" to be removed.